# JavaScript convert amount in words

Tags: javascript

I want to use JavaScript to convert amount in words.
used this code https://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/5tt7d3e6/

i want to print 6-digit number in thousands and 7-digit number in millions and so on. I do not want to print in Lakhs,Crores.

```
value = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if (i == 0 || i == 2 || i == 4 || i == 7) {
            value = n_array[i] * 10;
        } else {
            value = n_array[i];
        }
        if (value != 0) {
            words_string += words[value] + " ";
        }
        if ((i == 1 && value != 0) || (i == 0 && value != 0 && n_array[i + 1] == 0)) {
            words_string += "Crores ";
        }
        if ((i == 3 && value != 0) || (i == 2 && value != 0 && n_array[i + 1] == 0)) {
            words_string += "Lakhs ";
        }
        if ((i == 5 && value != 0) || (i == 4 && value != 0 && n_array[i + 1] == 0)) {
            words_string += "Thousand ";
        }
        if (i == 6 && value != 0 && (n_array[i + 1] != 0 && n_array[i + 2] != 0)) {
            words_string += "Hundred and ";
        } else if (i == 6 && value != 0) {
            words_string += "Hundred ";
        }
    }
    words_string = words_string.split("  ").join(" ");
```

Comment: what is in n_array[i]?

Comment: mind to use a plugin? https://www.cssscript.com/javascript-library-to-convert-numbers-to-words-numbertowordsjs/

Comment: you should debug to add logic to reference code :)

Comment: reference of above code is taken from https://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/5tt7d3e6/

Comment: If you don't want to use lakhs... why did you take that as an example?

Comment: I want to edit that code and use millions there. but i do not get it where to  edit that code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at jsfiddle. Hope it solves your issue

https://jsfiddle.net/thanseeh/neLcv6u8/43/

```
const arr = x => Array.from(x);
const num = x => Number(x) || 0;
const str = x => String(x);
const isEmpty = xs => xs.length === 0;
const take = n => xs => xs.slice(0,n);
const drop = n => xs => xs.slice(n);
const reverse = xs => xs.slice(0).reverse();
const comp = f => g => x => f (g (x));
const not = x => !x;
const chunk = n => xs =>
  isEmpty(xs) ? [] : [take(n)(xs), ...chunk (n) (drop (n) (xs))];

// numToWords :: (Number a, String a) => a -> String
let numToWords = n => {

  let a = [
    '', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four',
    'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine',
    'ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen',
    'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen'
  ];

  let b = [
    '', '', 'twenty', 'thirty', 'forty',
    'fifty', 'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety'
  ];

  let g = [
    '', 'thousand', 'million', 'billion', 'trillion', 'quadrillion',
    'quintillion', 'sextillion', 'septillion', 'octillion', 'nonillion'
  ];

  // this part is really nasty still
  // it might edit this again later to show how Monoids could fix this up
  let makeGroup = ([ones,tens,huns]) => {
    return [
      num(huns) === 0 ? '' : a[huns] + ' hundred ',
      num(ones) === 0 ? b[tens] : b[tens] && b[tens] + '-' || '',
      a[tens+ones] || a[ones]
    ].join('');
  };

  let thousand = (group,i) => group === '' ? group : `${group} ${g[i]}`;

  if (typeof n === 'number')
    return numToWords(String(n));
  else if (n === '0')
    return 'zero';
  else
    return comp (chunk(3)) (reverse) (arr(n))
      .map(makeGroup)
      .map(thousand)
      .filter(comp(not)(isEmpty))
      .reverse()
      .join(' ');
};

console.log(numToWords(55111222333));
//=> fifty-five billion one hundred eleven million two hundred 
//   twenty-two thousand three hundred thirty-three
```